# How can I find the solutions to this trigonometric equation in a specific interval?

Tags: trigonometry

since days I'm wondering how I can solve this equation:

$0 = \sin( \pi * \sqrt{x})-0.5$

The solution should be in the interval $[196,256]$.

My solution so far:

1. $\sin( \pi * \sqrt{X})= 0.5$
2. Substitution: $u = \pi * \sqrt{x}$
3. $\sin(u) = 0.5$
4. $u = \pi / 6$ +2∗∗,∈ℤ
5. Resubstitution: $u = \pi * \sqrt{x}$
6. $2*k*\pi+\pi/6 = \pi * \sqrt{x}.  $
7. $(12*k+1)^2/36 = x$
8. $-(12*k+1)^2/36 = x$

Now I've tried to set up an inequality with x >=196 and x<= 256 to see in which interval the variable k has to be. But now I don't know what I should do next...

As I've used Photomath, I know that there are more solutions. But I just can't find them. I'm also not able to solve the equation in the interval $[196,256]$.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me.

Have a nice day!

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type up your steps. Is $x$ in degrees or is it in radians?

Comment: "$f(x) = \sin(\pi \times \sqrt{x})-0.5$." You have omitted something.  What is it that you are trying to solve?  Are you looking for all $x$ in the interval $[196,256]$ such that $f(x) =0$?  If not, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: There is no equation to solve. You just gave an expression.

Comment: f(x) should be zero, so that sin(×‾‾√)−0.5=0

x is in radians

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your point 4. is incomplete

$\pi\sqrt x=\pi/6+2k\pi;\;\pi\sqrt x=\pi-\pi/6+2k\pi$

which leads to two possibilities

$x_1=\left(\frac{1}{6}+2k\right)^2;\;x_2=\left(\frac{5}{6}+2k\right)^2,\;k\in\mathbb{Z}$

Both of these set of values must be in the interval $[196,256]$

$196\le \left(\frac{1}{6}+2k\right)^2\le 256\to 14\le\frac16+2k\le16\to k=7\to x=\frac{7225}{36}\approx 200.694$

In a similar way we find

$14\le \frac{5}{6}+2k\le 16\to x=\frac{7921}{36}\approx 220.028$

Confirmed by the graph below

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the solution! You really saved me! I have only one question:
Why do you subtract from  /6+2? I don't get it why you do that...

Comment: @LenaSo $\sin 30°=\frac12$ but also $\sin(180°-30°)=\frac{1}{2}$. An angle and its supplementary have the same sine